# Why if statement to test for correct notation in Deg Min Sec ignoring condition?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a script with multiple functions, one of them taking the bearing for a direction distance traverse in ArcMAP, and tests to make sure the input follows the standard guidelines for Degrees Minutes Seconds. It checks for the North South and East West just fine, but when it gets to the actual numerical values for the direction, it fails when I enter N88-12-9E and goes to my conditional statement for "seconds cannot be greater than 60."

The code strips the N/S E/W from the beginning and end of the string, then removes the '-' with a split. Leaving a list of 3 numbers. In the case above, it leaves ['88', '12', '9'] where 9 is the seconds, 12 minutes, 88 degrees.

Here's the small tidbit of code with the if statement:

```
if dmSplit[1] >= '60' or dmSplit[-1] >= '60':
    while dmSplit[1] >= '60':
        print("\nMinutes must be less than 60.")
        bearing = str(raw_input("Enter the bearing (N/Sdeg-min-secE/W): "))
        bearing = string.upper(bearing)
        dms = bearing.strip('NSEW')
        dmSplit = dms.split('-', 2)
    while dmSplit[-1] >= '60':
        print("\nSeconds must be less than 60.")
        bearing = str(raw_input("Enter the bearing (N/Sdeg-min-secE/W): "))
        bearing = string.upper(bearing)
        dms = bearing.strip('NSEW')
        dmSplit = dms.split('-', 2)
```

Above that it processes the original split/strip before getting to the first iteration. I don't understand why when I input a valid DMS bearing, it responds with my error check...

Comment: Why aren't you using integers instead of strings?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even realize. God I feel stupid... Let me try that. Thanks! ---- nope. Still fails in the exact same way.

Comment: Watch out though, just changing the `'60'` values to `60` won't be sufficient, because in Python 2.7 any string is greater than any integer. So if `dmSplit[1]` is a string, then `dmSplit[1] >= 60` will always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that you are comparing strings as if they were integers.

For example:

```
'11' > '9'
```

will evaluate to `False`, because they are strings and are not compared as integers.

**So, how can you solve it?**

Just work with integers, or convert your strings to int before comparing:

```
int('11')
```

**Note:** Both of your operands have to be integers in order to get the desired result.

Comment: That would make sense... I've been staring at this code for hours while writing it and am kinda blind and don't see a lot of the human errors I make... Thanks!!

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter. I've worked it both ways unless my conditionals are off completely, it still fails the exact same way

Comment: Are you sure you are working only with integers? How have you converted the contents of `dmSplit`?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I finally found the blasted conversion that was failing higher up in the script! To answer, yes I did, however, I screwed up one of the conversions and it was staying as a string. The same one the error came from.